# Why program did not show answer in out.txt?

Tags: java, text, output, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

The code should do a reverse and output the result to out.txt, but this does not happen, can you explain my mistake in the code. Thanks in advance

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader input = new FileReader("in.txt");
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedReader sb = new BufferedReader(input);
        String data;

        while ((data = sb.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = data.split("                                  ");
            for (String a : words) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(a);
                builder.reverse();

                while ((sb.read()) != -1) {
                    output.write(String.valueOf(builder.reverse()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly *does not happen*? Is the file written? If yes, does it contain unexpected values or just none at all?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to call `builder.reverse()` twice? By the way, please [edit] your question to add your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reverse the string twice because of that the string is getting back to the original string. Also, there is an unnecessary (as per my understanding) `while` loop inside the `for` loop (I have removed that in my answer).

Try the below code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader input = new FileReader("in.txt");
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedReader sb = new BufferedReader(input);
        String data;

        while ((data = sb.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = data.split("                                  ");
            // above statement can be replaced with
            // String[] words = data.split(" {34}");
            for (String a : words) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(a);
                // why while loop is required?
                //while ((sb.read()) != -1) {
                    output.write(builder.reverse().toString());
                    output.flush(); // flush data to the file
                //}
            }
        }
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Read about File writer [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-filewriter-class) on how to `flush` data and also close the `writer` after writing is completed.